# How to open URL using web Browser Control in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

I am trying to open a webBrowser using webBrowser Control.

> C# Code

```
string uriString = "http://......."
Uri uri = new Uri(uriString);
this.DemoBrowser.Navigate(uri);
```

The problem that I am facing is , the URL is opening using "http" but giving below error when I am trying to open it using "https".

[image]

Any help is much appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Are you set isscriptenabled=true in your xaml web browser control

Comment: No @Shubham Sahu

Comment: so go ahead and set IsScriptEnabled="True" and reply if it works so i can provide full solution to this

Comment: It didn't work!!

Comment: Can you show url because in my case http and https both working

Comment: simply use
  
Browser.IsScriptEnabled = true;
      Browser.Navigate(new Uri("https ://google.com"));